# What's the best way to share an aurora serverless db cluster across accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm spinning up an aurora serverless db cluster in my org's main account, and am attempting to access it from one of many sub-accounts for the organization, however I'm getting the error message `Error: cluster arn:aws:rds:<region>:<mainaccount>:cluster:<clustername> does not belong to the calling account id <subaccount>`.  Previously I had connectivity working fine, when the cluster was spun up in the sub account, so this appears to be a purely IAM related issue from what I can tell.

So far I've tried:

- Sharing the cluster with all accounts in the org using the [AWS RAM](https://aws.amazon.com/ram/) console, which resulted in the same error.  Further research revealed that RAM for DB clusters appears to be more for giving cloning access rather than query access.
- Looking for ways to add policies to the cluster itself that gives the whole organization access to the resource (there doesn't appear to be any way to do this?)

The other thing I'm considering that I haven't tried yet because it feels too heavy (and probably too expensive?) to be the best way to do things:

- create a role in the main acct giving all org accts access
- add access to the role in the permissions of my db-access users in the sub account
- every time I go to make a db call, make an STS call to get temporary credentials to the role in the main account that has DB access
- use the temporary credentials to access the Data API

That seems more complex than I want it to be though so I thought I'd ask in case anyone knows of a better way--What's the best way to gain access to an aurora serverless cluster using the data api from a non-cluster-owning account in my organization?

Edit:
The statement I'm executing to access the DB has this form:

```
svc.ExecuteStatement(&rdsdataservice.ExecuteStatementInput{
    Schema:aws.String(schema),
    Database:aws.String(db),
    ResourceArn:aws.String(DatabaseARN),
    SecretArn:aws.String(SecretARN),
    Sql: aws.String(`SELECT ... `),
})
```

Comment: What specifically are you doing when you get that "does not belong to the calling account id" error? I wouldn't expect that when trying to connect and run SQL queries, unless you are using IAM DB authentication. Are you trying to allow multiple AWS accounts to *manage* the database cluster? Or are you only trying to allow multiple AWS accounts to make connections to the cluster and run SQL queries?

Comment: Just running rdsdataservice.New(...).ExecuteStatement(...).   I'm just hoping to be able to query from multiple accounts

Comment: So you're specifically trying to use the Serverless Data API.

Comment: Hoping to, yeah. I'm using a lot of lambdas and am hoping to avoid issues with connection management

Comment: For anyone reading this, I ended up using the method I laid out in the question.  Note that you're going to want to store the db-connection secrets in the same account as the role as well since you can't share secrets across accounts without doing a bunch of KMS key work.